# Mockito: Instant.now() returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am testing a UserRecord class using Mockito. The application is built using Java and Spring Boot framework:

```
@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class MyTests {
    @Mock
    private UserRecordEditor userRecordEditor;

    private static MockedStatic<Instant> mockInstant;

    private Integer userId = 1;
    private String oldUserName = "Keanu";
    private String newUserName = "Neo";

    @BeforeAll
    public static void init() {
        mockInstant = Mockito.mockStatic(Instant.class);  // Mockito will mock java.time.Instant using mockStatic
    }

    public UserRecord user1() {
        UserRecord userRecord = new UserRecord();
        userRecord.setId(userId);
        userRecord.setName(oldUserName);
        userRecord.setUpdateTime(Instant.of("2021-06-01T06:30:00.000Z"));
        userRecord.setCorrespondingCode("2021-06-01T06:30:00.000Z");
        return userRecord;
    }

    @Test
    public void updateTest() {
        log.info("Start test case: " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());

        Instant currentTimestamp = Instant.now();
        mockInstant.when(Instant::now).thenReturn(currentTimestamp);  //mock Instant.now()

        Mockito.when( userRecordRepository.getById(userId)).thenReturn(user1());
        Mockito.when(userRecordRepository.save(any(UserRecord.class))).then(i -> i.getArguments()[0]);

        UserRecord result = userRecordEditor.updateRecord(userId, newUserName);

        Assertions.assertEquals(result.getName(), newUserName);
        Assertions.assertEquals(result.getUpdateTime(), currentTimestamp);
        Assertions.assertEquals(result.getCorrespondingCode(), currentTimestamp.toString());

        log.info("End test case: " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
    }
}
```

UserRecord:

```
@Data
public class UserRecord() {
   private Integer id;

   private String name;

   private Instant updateTime;

   private String correspondingCode;
}
```

UserRecordEditor:

```
@Service
public class UserRecordEditor() {
    private UserRecordRepository userRecordRepository;

    public UserRecordEditor(UserRecordRepository userRecordRepository) {
        this.userRecordRepository = userRecordRepository;
    }

    public UserRecord updateRecord(Integer id, String name) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        Instant requestTime = Instant.now();
        UserRecord recordToUpdate = userRecordRepository.getById(id);

        if (recordToUpdate != null) {
            recordToUpdate.setName(name);
            // set update time
            recordToUpdate.setUpdateTime(requestTime);
            recordToUpdate.setCorrespondingCode( requestTime.toString() );
            

            return userRecordRepository.save(recordToUpdate);
        } else {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException();  // custom exception
        }
    }
}
```

UserRecordRepository:

```
public interface UserRecordRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRecord, Integer> {
    // default repository class with getById(id) and save(userRecord)
}
```

When running this test, I ran into a NullPointerException at this line:
`recordToUpdate.setCorrespondingCode(requestTime.toString());`

This indicates that `requestTime` is null, but why exactly does it become null? How can this problem be resolved?

Note that I have tried to parse a date string like this but it doesn't work:

`Instant currentTimestamp = Instant.of("2021-12-02T:06:30:00.000Z");`

Comment: As the code under test never calls `Instant.now()` why are you mocking it? Just create an instant in your test and pass it. And in your last paragraph, what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Edited. Also, using `Instant currentTimestamp = Instant.of("2021-12-02T:06:30:00.000Z");` throws NullPointerException.

Comment: Remove all the mocking of `Instant` and update your question.

Comment: should be good. note that `setUpdateTime()` function uses variable `requestTime`, which is instantiated to `Instant.now()` when `updateRecord()` function is entered.

Comment: Now that you have changed your function so that the code under test *does* call `Instant.now()` you *will* need to mock `Instant` if you want to be able to check that updateTime and correspondingCode are set correctly.

Comment: Using `mockInstant = Mockito.mockStatic(Instant.class)` for this purpose.

Comment: If you pass a clock to Instant.now you won't have to mock a static method, there is a fixed clock that tests can use. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51525990/217324

Comment: see [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55289157/mock-instant-now-without-using-clock-into-constructor-or-without-clock-object/70186748#70186748) explaining how to achieve mocking capability of Instant